# how to clean up aws resources with terraform state file

Tags: terraform, terraform-cdk, terraform-state

How can I delete all AWS resources described in a terraform state file stored in S3?

I am using [CDKTF](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/cdktf) and I find myself in a scenario frequently- I have evolved my Typescript code beyond what was last used for the serialized "plan".

For example, I decided to change the name of my stack, which resulted in a different name for my state file, so I have multiple state files describing AWS resources at different points during my refactoring.

Often my goal is to just start over and delete everything.

Answer (score 0):

terraform destroy -state= will cleanup the resources.

Comment: that gives me an error. `terraform destroy -state=myorg-X.tfstate

│ Error: failed to read schema for aws_route53_zone.X in registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/aws: failed to instantiate provider "registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/aws" to obtain schema: unavailable provider "registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/aws"`